# If $A$ is any set, is $\overline{\text{int}(A)}\subseteq \text{int}(\overline{A})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I already know that the inclusion does not work the other way by examining $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$, but is this inclusion true? If not, what serves as a counter example?

Comment: $\overline{interior(A)}\subseteq \overline{A}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true even for $A = (0,1)$.

Comment: Of course I overlook the simplest counter-example. Thanks for the help.